# csrss.exe runs slowly for an hour

Tags: windows-7, windows, csrss.exe

The last few days, csrss.exe has been slowing down my computer when doing one specific thing, at around 5-6pm(GMT+1) only. EDIT: Apparently, not always at that time. Just happened shortly around 7:30 PM.
The one specific thing is changing the mouse cursor icon, by any means -- Either just moving my mouse over the side of a window showing the resize icon, or anything else really. After doing this a few times, my computer would hang for a few seconds. It's also showing wrongly loaded icons in some cases, most notably the I-bar shows a corrupted icon, and sometimes the icon won't change at all.

Of course, my first intuition was that I was infected with some kind of malware, but as it turns out, unless this infection is a record-breakingly amazing stealth virus, I'm clean of any infections. It would also be pretty weird behaviour for a virus, I think.
Adding that to the fact that I browse very carefully, with noscript and adblockplus, I'm ruling out the possibility of a virus.

I'm currently going to see which module is causing the lags by checking it in process explorer, but it's probably an ntdll.dll module.

EDIT: Process explorer apparently found that the program causing lag was itself, whilst task manager still says it's csrss.exe...

Any help would be appreciated. And of course, if you need any more information, ask ahead.

Comment: In such cases is imho better if you first shot, und then ask.

Comment: install the WPT, follow my steps here: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD and capture the next time you see ths 60s of the high CPU usage.

Comment: @Dave Rook Yes, definitely. I did so many virusscans that I am pretty certain that area is safe.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I'll try that next time the problem occurs. Edit: It seems to be for Windows 8.1, not Windows 7?